# Error creating a line graph on winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graph

[image: Error image]
I keep getting this error when trying to initialise the form with my graph on it. Can't figure out a work around for it. Think it has something to do with Data Binding

Any ideas ?

Here is my code -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace NoCAnalysisTool2
{

    public partial class Visualisation : UserControl
    {
        public string tx_graph { get; set; }
        public List<int> tx_graphData { get; set; }
        public Visualisation(string txGraph, List<int> tx_GData)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tx_graph = txGraph;
            tx_graphData = tx_GData;

            // Set 3D chart settings
            chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.IsRightAngleAxes = false;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 40;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Rotation = 20;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.LightStyle = LightStyle.Realistic;

            // Populate series with random data
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(random.Next(45, 95));
                chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(random.Next(5, 75));
            }

            // Set series chart type
            chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;

            // Set point labels
            chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

            // Enable X axis margin
            chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;

            // Enable the ShowMarkerLines
            chart1.Series["Series1"]["ShowMarkerLines"] = "true";
            chart1.Series["Series2"]["ShowMarkerLines"] = "true";
        }

        private void TxGraph_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Tx_graph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        private void Visualisation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


            private void chart11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: the deadline for this project is 3 days so i need to get some headway on this issue to get it in on time

Comment: Please read the post I linked to. TLDR; questions which need to be answered quickly tend to be low-quality questions which attract low-quality answers. You and the community will both benefit if you read [ask].

Comment: Your image is unclickable, too small to read, and unsearchable. Please do not use images to provide critical information in your question. All error message text, exception stack traces, and other pertinent information should be provided as **text**, copied verbatim into the question itself. Please **do** take the time to produce a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. The long-term goal of Stack Overflow is to provide a repository of useful questions and answers to help future readers. In that view, your own deadline and rush to post the question are irrelevant and harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **'default'** `ChartArea` is not called `"Default"` but `"ChartArea1"`.

**Trying to access an indexer by a wrong name results in an Argument Exeption.**

You have the choice of either calling it by its index:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
```

Or by its right name:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"];
```

Or set the `Name` property th a string you like..:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name = "Default";
```

..and then calli it by that `Name`:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

Btw: I hope you have added the 2nd Series in the designer and given it the right Name ;-)